# Multiply matrices in C using 3 arrays

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to write an algorithm that calculates 2 nxn matrices using 3 arrays per matrix.

For example

```
int m1Row[] =     {1,1,2,2};
int m1Column[] =  {1,2,1,2};
int m1Value[] =   {1,2,3,4};
int m2Row[] =     {1,1,2,2};
int m2Column[] =  {1,2,1,2};
int m2Value[] =   {4,3,2,1};
```

represents 2 matrices. m1Value[x] is the value of matrix 1 at row m1Row[x] and column m1Column[x].

m1:

```
1  2           
3  4
```

m2:

```
4  3
2  1
```

The code I wrote somehow works for some matrices but not for every one. The problem is probably that I am missing the part where you have to add some values to each other to multiply two matrices. [Here's an example from wikipedia.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaAhn.png)

Example of correctly calculated matrices (m = count of numbers not equal to zero):

```
int m = 4;
int n = 8;
int m1Row[] =     {1, 2, 3, 3};
int m1Column[] =  {1, 2, 1, 3};
int m1Value[] =   {1, 2, 3, 4};
int m2Row[] =     {1, 2, 3, 3};
int m2Column[] =  {3, 2, 1, 2};
int m2Value[] =   {7, 3, 1, 2};
```

I already thought about this problem for hours and tried some other for-loops and everything but it just made it worse and no value was correct or it calculated way too many values.

I hope somebody can help me get this code working so that the result matrix is calculated correctly.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //************************
    int m = 4;
    int n = 8;
    int m1Row[] =     {1, 2, 3, 3};
    int m1Column[] =  {1, 2, 1, 3};
    int m1Value[] =   {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int m2Row[] =     {1, 2, 3, 3};
    int m2Column[] =  {3, 2, 1, 2};
    int m2Value[] =   {7, 3, 1, 2};
    //************************
    int resultRow[50];                       //result matrix, 50 is just a placeholder
    int resultColumn[50];
    int resultValue[50];
    int reminder = 0;
    int resultBuffer = 0;
    int saveIndex = 0;
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= n;) {
        if(m1Row[reminder] == i) {

            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                
                if(m2Row[j] == m1Column[reminder]) {
                    resultBuffer = m2Value[j] * m1Value[reminder];
                    
                    //save result
                    resultRow[saveIndex] = m1Row[reminder];             //save  row number
                    resultColumn[saveIndex] = m2Column[j];              //save column number
                    resultValue[saveIndex] = resultBuffer;              //save value
                    saveIndex++;
                }
            }
            reminder++;
            
        } else { i++; }
    }

    //print results
    printf("resultRow[] resultColumn[] resultValue[]\n");
    for(int i = 0; i <= reminder; i++) {
        printf("\t%d\t\t\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\n", resultRow[i], resultColumn[i], resultValue[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To multiply two matrices, C = A*B, we have the formula C[i,k] = sum_j A[i,j] * B [j,k]. Since you are using sparse matrices, and you don't want to iterate on all the cells that are going to be 0, you need to somehow build that sum the other way around, by iterating on the non-zero values and adding their contribution where it's needed.

Comment: ([Nirav Bhuva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17647086/nirav-bhuva) posted an entirely similar question just days ago. And has [re-asked it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70325643), leaving out the code.)

Comment: There's a bunch of existing libraries that do this. Why not just use one of those?